# How to create a view of all the nodes sorted by date width header per each year

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I need to create a view like this:

2012

node/1, node/2

---

2011

node/3, node/4

---

2010

node/5, node/6

---

The nodes have to be grouped by date and add the header with the year.

I don't want to create one view per each year but just one view. Shall i do it using taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'VE FOUND THE SOLUTION:

I created a view with fields, i added the field date, under "format -> setting" i used the option Grouping by and I selected the date field and here we go!